# jQuery slide up/down effect not working on div

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Developing ASP.NET Web Forms application using VS 2010 & have a login textbox and password textbox on a page.

Above those I have a simple div tag which will contain the error message if the login textbox or password textbox is empty.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/d9Wwj/)

`<div id="ErrorDiv"></div>`

I wanted this div to slide down showing error message if either text box are empty

Following is jQuery code I have tried:

```
<script>
$(function () {

    $("#btnLogin").click(function () {    
        var error = 0;

        if (error == 0) {
            $("#ErrorDiv").slideToggle();
        }

        if ($("#txtLoginID").val() == "") {   
            error = 1;
            $("#ErrorDiv").text("Please Enter LoginID");
        }

        if ($("#txtPassword").val() == "") {
            error = 1;
            $("#ErrorDiv").text("Please Enter Password");
        }

        if (error == 1) {
            alert(document.getElementById("ErrorDiv").value());        
            $("#ErrorDiv").show(); 
        }

        else {
            alert(document.getElementById("ErrorDiv").value());
            $("#ErrorDiv").slideUP();
        }  
    });   
});
</script>
```

This does not work.

I also tried replacing  `$("#ErrorDiv").text("Please Enter LoginID");` with `$("#ErrorDiv").html("Please Enter LoginID");` but that had no effect.

What can be the problem?

Comment: can you please share a jsFiddle for this

Comment: or post the html (rendered, not asp)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/d9Wwj/

Comment: @Freelancer you can't use asp tag in fiddle , just use html tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all this line won't work

```
$("#ErrorDiv").slideUP();
```

it should be

```
$("#ErrorDiv").slideUp(); //lower case p
```

Secondly your alert `document.getElementById("ErrorDiv").value` won't work as it's a div so it wont have a value. You could alert it's innerHTML `document.getElementById("ErrorDiv").innerHTML` or use jQuery `$('#ErrorDiv').text()`

I also don't see the point in your first `if` statement

```
if(error == 0)
```

As your setting the variable error to 0 everytime the button is clicked so this statement will always run. You may as well always slideToggle the `div` if this is what you wanted to do, like so

```
var error = 0;
$('#ErrorDiv').slideToggle();
```

I've update your fiddle here -> http://jsfiddle.net/d9Wwj/3/
I've changed some of your logic as well. You also weren't clearing your `ErrorDiv` when there were no more errors.

Below is the finished article

```
$((function(){
  $("#btnLogin").click(function (){
     var error = "";
     $('#ErrorDiv').slideToggle();

     if($("#txtLoginID").val() == ""){
         error += "Please Enter LoginID";
     }
     if($("#txtPassword").val() == ""){
        if(error){
           error += "<br />Please enter a password";   
        } else {
           error += "Please enter a Password";  
        }        
     }

     if(!error){
        $("#ErrorDiv").html("").slideUp();
     } else {
        $('#ErrorDiv').html(error).slideDown();
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: @Freelancer I've updated your fiddle please see my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div id="ErrorDiv" style="display:none;">Error</div>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="txtLoginID"/>
    <input type="password" id="txtPassword"/>
    <input type="submit" id="btnLogin"/>
</form>
```

Script:

```
$("#btnLogin").click(function() {
    var error = '';
    if (error == '') {
        $("#ErrorDiv").hide();
    }
    if ($("#txtLoginID").val() == "") {
        error = 'Please Enter LoginID \n';
    }
    if ($("#txtPassword").val() == "") {
        error += 'Please Enter Password'
    }
    if (error != '') {
        alert(error);
        $("#ErrorDiv").text(error).show();
    } else {
        $("#ErrorDiv").slideUP();
    }
    return false;
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s9nWY/)